# Show multiple targets output in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, output, targets

I am doing a C++ Xcode project. I have two different targets (client and server) with .cpp files associated to them and main() functions and everything working. I created two schemes to build and run each of them separately, and it works perfectly.
Then I duplicated the client scheme, added the server as an additional target to compile and build, but when I run this, only the output from the client target is shown in the lower part of the screen.
What does this mean? The server isn't run? Is it run but the output is hidden somewhere? How do I get something like an output window with the two outputs of the two targets running at the same time when I run the client server scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hit cmd+6 in Xcode or alternatively go to View > Navigators > Show Debug Navigator, you can select between your multiple running targets.  The console output will change to whichever target is selected.